# How to add characters to a string in specific indexes?

Tags: java, string, char

I have a string formed with 6 letters eg: "abcdef".
I need to add "." every two characters so it would be like this: "ab.cd.ef". 
I'm working in java, I tried this:

```
private String FormatAddress(String sourceAddress) {
    char[] sourceAddressFormatted = new char[8];
    sourceAddress.getChars(0, 1, sourceAddressFormatted, 0);
    sourceAddress += ".";
    sourceAddress.getChars(2, 3, sourceAddressFormatted, 3);
    sourceAddress += ".";
    sourceAddress.getChars(4, 5, sourceAddressFormatted, 6);
    String s = new String(sourceAddressFormatted);
    return s;
}
```

But i received strange values such as [C@2723b6.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix it as

```
    String sourceAddress = "abcdef";
    String s = sourceAddress.substring(0, 2);
    s += ".";
    s += sourceAddress.substring(2, 4);
    s += ".";
    s += sourceAddress.substring(4, 6);
    System.out.println(s);
```

You also can do the same with regex, it's a one line solution

```
    String s = sourceAddress.replaceAll("(\\w\\w)(?=\\w\\w)", "$1.");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try regexp:

**Input:**

```
abcdef
```

**Code:**

```
System.out.println("abcdef".replaceAll(".{2}(?!$)", "$0."));
```

**Output:**

```
ab.cd.ef
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String result="";
String str ="abcdef";
for(int i =2; i<str.length(); i=i+2){
     result = result + str.substring(i-2 , i) + ".";
}
result = result + str.substring(str.length()-2);
```

Comment: The last two letters won't be added this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String formatAddress(String sourceAddress) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceAddress.length(); i+=2) {
        sb.append(sourceAddress.substring(i, i+2));
        if (i != sourceAddress.length()-1) {
            sb.append('.');
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```